# Visual Basic (VB.NET) example code to send SendGrid email by a VB.NET windows app

Tags: visual-studio, email, smtp, sendgrid

I just got my SendGrid account installed on my AWS EC2 Windows server 2019 my VS 2019 Pro for my VB.NET windows app.

But all the examples I can find are in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got same problem same as you.
I already developed and tested for both C#.NET and VB.NET.
C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestSendGrid().Wait();
        }

        static async Task TestSendGrid()
        {
            try
            {
                var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SENDGRID_APIKEY"];
                var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
                var msg = new SendGridMessage()
                {
                    From = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Test User"),
                    Subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid C#.NET SDK!",
                    PlainTextContent = "Hello, Email!",
                    HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
                };
                msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Test User"));
                var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

VB.NET

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Configuration
Imports SendGrid
Imports SendGrid.Helpers.Mail

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        TestSendGrid().Wait()
    End Sub

    Private Async Function TestSendGrid() As Task
        Try
            Dim apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SENDGRID_APIKEY")
            Dim client = New SendGridClient(apiKey)
            Dim msg = New SendGridMessage() With {
                .From = New EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Test User"),
                .Subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid VB.NET SDK!",
                .PlainTextContent = "Hello, Email!",
                .HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
            }
            msg.AddTo(New EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Test User"))
            Dim response = Await client.SendEmailAsync(msg)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
End Module
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any either.  Especially in v3. I finally got it working in VB.NET. Hopefully this will save someone some time.  That being said, I eventually switched to mailgun because the functionality was way more robust than sendgrid...

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SendEmail()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub SendEmail()
        Dim apiKey = "put your api key here ... should start with sg.something"
        Dim sg = New SendGridAPIClient(apiKey)

        Dim from = New Email("billgates@microsoft.com")
        Dim subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid CSharp Library!"
        Dim sto = New Email("barakobama@whitehouse.gov")
        Dim content = New Content("text/plain", "Hello, Email!")
        Dim mail = New Mail(from, subject, sto, content)
        Dim response = Await sg.client.mail.send.post(requestBody:=mail.[Get]())
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What do I add to References to get 'SendGridAPIClient' ?

Comment: Imports SendGrid at the top of the class.  Before you do that though, use NuGet to install SendGrid to the project

Answer (score 0):

> This code is working for SendGrid

```
Imports SendGrid.Helpers.Mail
Imports SendGrid    
            Public Sub SchedularCallback(ByRef data As EmailDataBulk)               
                Try 
                        SchedularCallbackGrid(data)                     
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            End Sub
             Public Async sub SchedularCallbackGrid()      
                Dim response As Response
                Try

                    Dim client = New SendGridClient("Send grid api Key")
                    Dim from = New EmailAddress("from sample mailID", "From mail name") '' Login Email and Display Its name in mail,on Inbox
                    Dim subject = "Hello Email!"
                    Dim sto = New EmailAddress("Recepient EmailID", "")
                    Dim plainTextContent = "Content"
                    Dim htmlContent = "Content"
                    Dim msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, sto, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent)
                    response = Await client.SendEmailAsync(msg)            

                Catch ex As Exception           
                    Throw ex
                End Try

            End sub
        End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

With this one, while there is no error, I'm not getting a message into sendgrid. My stats should show a mail being received and there is nothing. I converted C# code into vb.net and it made a Module. I had problems with it as a module so I changed it to a class and I'm creating an instance of it and calling it in the button_click event. Any ideas why I'm not getting an email?

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Configuration
Imports SendGrid
Imports SendGrid.Helpers.Mail
Class sendgrid1
    Sub Main(ByVal test As String)
        TestSendGrid(test).Wait()
    End Sub

    Private Async Function TestSendGrid(ByVal test As String) As Task
        Try
            Dim apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ApiKey")
            Dim client = New SendGridClient(apiKey)
            Dim msg = New Helpers.Mail.SendGridMessage() With {
                .From = New EmailAddress("admin@pacificwestcapital.net", test),
                .Subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid VB.NET SDK!",
                .PlainTextContent = "Hello, Email!",
                .HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
            }
            msg.AddTo(New EmailAddress("test@test.com", "Test"))
            Dim response = Await client.SendEmailAsync(msg)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
Partial Class admin_sendgrid
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sg As New sendgrid1
        Call sg.Main("Test")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Threading
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Imports SendGrid
Imports System.Net


' Create the email object first, then add the properties.
Dim myMessage As SendGridMessage
myMessage = New SendGridMessage()

' Add the message properties.
myMessage.From = New MailAddress("<my email addr>")

' Add multiple addresses to the To field.



myMessage.AddTo("<destination email addr 1>")
myMessage.AddTo("<destination email addr 2>")
myMessage.AddTo("<destination email addr 3>")
myMessage.Subject = "Testing the SendGrid Library 2"

'Add the HTML and Text bodies
myMessage.Html = "<p>Hello World!</p>"
myMessage.Text = "Hello World plain text!"

Dim credentials As NetworkCredential


credentials = New NetworkCredential("apikey", "<my api pw>")
transportWeb = New Web(credentials)
transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage)
```