# Sendgrid VB.net integration

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have copied the example from this post here at
[Visual Basic (VB.NET) example code to send SendGrid email by a VB.NET windows app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33972385/visual-basic-vb-net-example-code-to-send-sendgrid-email-by-a-vb-net-windows-ap/70128050#70128050)

to get this working in my vb website.  I was able to get this to debug by changing the Module to a Class.  It would not work as a module for me. I have uploaded it and placed my key into the web.config file. When I click the button at my live site, I don't receive an email. Also, when I check at Sendgrid.com for email stats, everything is zeroed out with no record of receiving any emails to forward. Here is my code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Configuration
Imports SendGrid
Imports SendGrid.Helpers.Mail
Class sendgrid1
    Sub Main(ByVal test As String)
        TestSendGrid(test).Wait()
    End Sub

    Private Async Function TestSendGrid(ByVal test As String) As Task
        Try
            Dim apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ApiKey")
            Dim client = New SendGridClient(apiKey)
            Dim msg = New Helpers.Mail.SendGridMessage() With {
                .From = New EmailAddress("admin@pacificwestcapital.net", test),
                .Subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid VB.NET SDK!",
                .PlainTextContent = "Hello, Email!",
                .HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
            }
            msg.AddTo(New EmailAddress("pacwestcapital@aol.com", "Scot King"))
            Dim response = Await client.SendEmailAsync(msg)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
Partial Class admin_sendgrid
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sg As New sendgrid1
        Call sg.Main("Scot King")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can someone possibly explain why it isn't working?

Comment: Does the code raise an error? Or log an error from the `Catch` block? Have you verified the email address you are sending from, or authenticated the domain with SendGrid?

Comment: Yes, I gave up with this stuff. I'm just using SMTP to send over there now.